# Preimage of a point under the Hopf map

Tags: algebraic-topology, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, hopf-fibration

Considering the Hopf map $S^3 \longrightarrow S^2$ given by $$(x,y,z,w) \mapsto \bigl(x^2+y^2-z^2-w^2,2(xw+yz),2(yw-xz)\bigr),$$
I know that the preimage of point is a great circle in $S^3$. For example, the preimage of $(1,0,0)$ is the set $$\left\{(x,y,0,0) \in S^3\right\}.$$
I am trying to get the formula for a general point; taking a point $(X,Y,Z)$ in $S^2$, we have the following system of non-linear equations:
$$\begin{cases} x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1, \\ x^2+y^2-z^2-w^2=X, \\ 2(xw+yz)=Y, \\ 2(yw-xz)=Z.  \end{cases}$$ I don't know how to solve this system for $x, y, z$ and $w$.

Comment: I think you would be better off working with complex coordinates instead of real. $(z,w)\in S^3\subset \Bbb C^2$ maps to $w/z\in\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks Ted. Your comment was very helpful.